# How to pass arguments to stored callbacks?

Tags: rust

Given a "delegate" struct that has a "handler" member, how can I invoked the handler with a dynamic string?

```
pub struct Processor {
    callback: Box<FnMut()>,
    message: Option<String>
}

impl Processor {
    pub fn new<CB: 'static + FnMut()>(c: CB) -> Self {
        Processor {
            callback: Box::new(c),
            message: Some("".into())
        }
    }

    pub fn set_callback<CB: 'static + FnMut(&str)>(&mut self, callback: CB) {
        self.callback = Box::new(callback);
    }

    pub fn set_message<S>(&mut self, message: S) where S: Into<String> {
        self.message = Some(message.into());
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        match self.message {
            Some(string) => {
                if self.message.chars().count() > 0 {
                    (self.callback)(self.message);
                } else {
                    (self.callback)();
                }
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }
}

impl EventEmitter {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        EventEmitter {
            delegates: Vec::new()
        }
    }

    /// Register an Event and a handler
    pub fn on(&mut self, event: Event, handler: Processor) {
        self.delegates.push(Delegate::new(event, handler))
    }

    /// Run handlers on the emitted event
    pub fn emit(&mut self, name: &'static str/*, with message!! */) {
        for delegate in self.delegates.iter_mut(){
            if delegate.event.name == name {
                delegate.handler.process();
            }
        }
    }

    /// Run handlers on the emitted event
    pub fn emit_with(&mut self, name: &'static str, message: &'static str) {
        for delegate in self.delegates.iter_mut() {
            if delegate.event.name == name {
                delegate.handler.set_message(message);
                delegate.handler.process();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then later on I have:

```
emitter.on(
    Event::new("TEST"), 
    Processor::new(|x| println!("Test: {}", x))
);
emitter.emit_with("TEST", "test");
```

But the compiler complains:

```
  --> src/main.rs:97:3
   |
97 |         Processor::new(|x| println!("Test: {}", x))
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ --- takes 1 argument
   |         |
   |         expected closure that takes 0 arguments
```

If I remove the "&str" type argument in the set_callback() definition:

```
set_callback<CB: 'static + FnMut()>(&mut self, callback: CB)
```

I can get this to work using a closure that does not take any arguments:

```
emitter.on( // emitter.emit("TEST");
    Event::new("TEST"), 
    Processor::new(|| println!("static string."))
);
```

Is there a way to pass a String to the emit_with() function that can ultimately be passed to the handler?

Comment: Please provide a full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), because currently the types `Delegate`, `EventEmitter`, `Event` and `CB` are missing. You could use [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) to create and share one

Comment: Since there is no verifiable code in my hand I am guessing,
Your Process new method does not taking parameterized closure: `pub fn new<CB: 'static + FnMut()>(c: CB) -> Self`

You can start changing it like following: `pub fn new<CB: 'static + FnMut(String)>(c: CB) -> Self`

Comment: `callback: Box<FnMut()>,` you are defining a closure that takes no parameters. I don't know what you are expecting. Can you please a bite more clear about that? E.g. provide an example that does not work, but you want it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have written:

```rust
pub struct Processor {
    callback: Box<FnMut(/* RIGHT HERE */)>,
    message: Option<String>
}
```

You have declared a `FnMut` (a closure) that takes no arguments.
The syntax is `FnMut(/* arguments to closure */)`, but you have not provided any. As such, you cannot pass it a closure that *does* take arguments.
**You cannot have a closure that both takes an argument and doesn't take an argument at the same time.**

Additionally, you used `FnMut(&str)`, but only at *one place*. You need it at all places. Since you want to either pass or not pass the string, I have converted it to a `Optional<&str>` (so that the closure type is `FnMut(Option<&str>)`).

I have modified your code such that the closure takes an optional `&str`.
This is how I would suggest you handle this:

```rust
pub struct Processor {
    // The closure takes an optional string.
    callback: Box<FnMut(Option<&str>)>,
    message: Option<String>
}

impl Processor {
    pub fn new<CB: 'static + FnMut(Option<&str>)>(c: CB) -> Self {
        Processor {
            callback: Box::new(c),
            message: Some("".into())
        }
    }

    pub fn set_callback<CB: 'static + FnMut(Option<&str>)>(&mut self, callback: CB) {
        self.callback = Box::new(callback);
    }

    pub fn set_message<S>(&mut self, message: S) where S: Into<String> {
        self.message = Some(message.into());
    }

    pub fn process(&mut self) {
        match self.message {
            Some(string) => {
                // NOTE: Instead of .chars().count > 0
                if !self.message.is_empty() {
                    (self.callback)(Some(self.message));
                } else {
                    (self.callback)(None);
                }
            },
            None => {}
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE**: This is untested, but should probably work. If any errors come up, do comment.